# How to distribute data from json column of mysql database to html table created with php foreach

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, json

I'm creating web application connected to mysql database by myself.

In database there are many columns and one column is json format, that I implemented recently.

example of one row of that column in database:
column name: sold_data

```
[{"qty_sold": "10", "buyer_id": "01", "sell_price": "234", "date": "01.01.2022"}, {"qty_sold": "2", "buyer_id": "0101", "sell_price": "436", "date": "10.1.2023 "}]
```

other columns are just strings or numbers, with those are easy to deal.

Now I can't Distribute this data to appropriate column in html table.

show-inventory.php:

```
<?php
  include('connection.php');
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM inventory0 ORDER BY id DESC");
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  return $stmt->fetchAll();
 ?>
```

php part in header of html file:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) header('location: login.php');
  $_SESSION['table'] = 'inventory0';
  $user = $_SESSION['user'];
  $products = include('database/show-inventory.php');
 ?>
```

table tbody part in html file where I put sold_data column:

```
                   <tbody>
                      <?php foreach($products as $index => $user){ ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td><?= $user['descr'] ?></td>
                          <td><?= $user['prod_id'] ?></td>
                          <td><?= $user['notes'] ?></td>
                          <!-- and so on... -->


                          <td><?= $user['sold_data'] ?></td>                          

                      <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
```

I know this is wrong but cant figure out it ... (see screenshot)

screenshot :
[screenshot of that column in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnoNq.jpg)

I was searching solution 2 days already but I cant find one to solve this. I'm new and not so good at programming, so confused and stuck. I couldn't even find different approach without using php. So Im not mentioning other examples I used, they were useless and very bad.

Result I want to achieve :
[Result I want to achieve could look like this in red circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLpnq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve as below

```
[{"qty_sold": "10", "buyer_id": "01", "sell_price": "234", "date": "01.01.2022"}, {"qty_sold": "2", "buyer_id": "0101", "sell_price": "436", "date": "10.1.2023 "}]

function hamburger($bas, $son, $yazi){
@preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($bas, '/') .
'(.*?)'. preg_quote($son, '/').'/i', $yazi, $m);
return @$m[1];
}
```

usage

```
$baslik = hamburger("{", "}", $data);

foreach($baslik as $b){
$d=array_map(function ($input){return explode(':',$input);},explode(',',$b));
echo $d[0][0]."=>".$d[0][1];
}
```